# How to get clearInterval to work with a button using Javascript/jQuery (not a variable/interval ID issue)

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, setinterval, clearinterval

Trying to implement clearInterval to stop the continuous display of user-inputted strings.

This isn't an interval ID issue, as I have defined the setInterval function as a variable already (and still not working):

```
oldHandle = setInterval(function () {
```

But I'm trying to link the clearInterval function to a button, so that when it's pressed, the display will stop looping thru the user inputted strings.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sean1rose/sKadX/14/)

HTML:

```
<h1 id='output'></h1>

<title>FORM</title>
<form id="frm">
    <input id="txt" type="text" placeholder="Type something tasty..." name="text">
    <label>1 at a time:
        <input id='autoListen' type="checkbox" name="autoListen">
    </label>
    <input id='submitBtn' type="submit" value="OK">
        <input type="button" value="Stop" onclick="stopDisplay()">
        <div class="controlbox">
        <div class="controlpanel"></div>
        </div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var txtBox = $('#txt');
    var frm = $('#frm');
    var output = $('#output');
    var subBtn = $('#submitBtn');
    var container = [];
    var oldHandle;

    frm.submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var result = txtBox.val();
        var $entry = $("<p>" + result + "</p>");

        container.push(result);
        $(".controlpanel").append($entry);

        var i = 0;
        clearInterval(oldHandle);
        oldHandle = setInterval(function () {
            if (i >= container.length) {
                i = 0;
            }
            if (container.length > 0) {
                output.text(container[i]);
                console.log(container[i]);
                ++i;
            } else {
                output.empty();
                clearInterval(oldHandle);
            }
        }, 2500)

        txtBox.val('');
    });

    $('#autoListen').click(function () {

        if ($('#autoListen').is(':checked')) {

            subBtn.hide();
            output.text(txtBox.val());

            txtBox.keyup(function () {
                output.text(txtBox.val());
            })

        } else {
            subBtn.show();
            txtBox.unbind('keyup');
        }
    });

    $(".controlbox").on('dblclick', 'p', function() {
        var $entry = $(this);
        container.splice($entry.index(), 1);
        $entry.remove();
    });

    function stopDisplay(){
        clearInterval(oldHandle);
    };
});
```

Any ideas as to where I'm going wrong??? Is this a scope issue? Am I defining the clearInterval function in an improper place? Or maybe my button isn't set up properly? I tried following clearInterval examples I found, to no avail...

Note: The Stop button can be found on Line 10 of HTML, the setInterval function on Line 20 of JS, and the stopDisplay/clearInterval function on line 60 of JS

Also: feel free to try out the interface - type in multiple strings, they'll display and re-display on constant loop. I'm trying to get them to stop looping thru the display upon the click of the stop button...

Comment: Error in console: "Uncaught ReferenceError: stopDisplay is not defined "

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should have been solved by looking at the error log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `stopDisplay` function is defined within an anonymous function, not in the global scope. So it's not accessible to inline Javascript in the `onclick` attribute.

The best fix is to bind the click handler with jQuery rather than the `onclick` attribute. Give it an ID:

```
<input id="stop" type="button" value="Stop">
```

and in your jQuery do:

```
$("#stop").click(stopDisplay);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the line:

var oldHandle;

I believe that will solve your scope issue and get you on the right track.

Comment: if you mean the one just after `$(document).ready` - no, it shouldn't be removed.

Comment: If you expect the stopDisplay function to work, you're going to need for oldHandle to be a global.  Did you try removing the var?

Comment: It would be so if `stopDisplay` was global, which it isn't. But please see the other answer for a better solution than making the function and the variable global